# Infinite dimensional reps of the rotation group

Tags: representation-theory, mathematical-physics, rotations

$\mathbf{Background:}$

The following is paraphrased from ``Representations of the rotation and Lorentz groups and their applications,'' by Gel'fand.

Consider a finite-dimensional representation $T: SO_3 \to GL_n$ of the rotation group.  Label elements of $SO_3$ as $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$.  We have (for real $s,t$):
\begin{align}
T_{jk}[s \cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)] \cdot T_{kl}[t \cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)] = T_{jl}[(s+t)\cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)]
\end{align}
Applying $\frac{d}{ds} \rvert_{s=0}$ to both sides (assuming $T$ is such that we can do this), we get:
\begin{align}
\theta_a \cdot A^a_{jk} \cdot  T_{kl}[t \cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)] = \frac{d}{dt} T_{jl} [t\cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)]
\end{align}
where:
\begin{align}
A^a = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_a} \rvert_{\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \theta_3 = 0}\ T[(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)]
\end{align}
The solution of these differential equations is:
\begin{align}
T_{jk}[t\cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)] = (\exp [ t \cdot \theta_a \cdot A^a ])_{jk}
\end{align}
Setting $t=1$, we see that the representation $T$ is completely determined if we are given the matrices $A^1,A^2,A^3$.

$\mathbf{Question:}$

Consider an infinite dimensional rep $T : SO_3 \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$.  Can the above argument be made rigorous in this case, with $A^1, A^2, A^3$ as differential operators?

One problem is that the equation
\begin{align}
\theta_a \cdot A^a \cdot  T[t \cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)] = \frac{d}{dt} T [t\cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)]
\end{align}
is no longer a system of (finitely many) ordinary differential equations.  Also, I'm not sure if $A^a = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_a} \rvert_{\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \theta_3 = 0}\ T[(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)]$ is well-defined.

Writing rotation vectors ($\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$) in spherical coordinates instead of cartesian, Gel'fand gets, for instance, $A^z \sim \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$, where $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle.  That's what I'm trying to justify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where gel'fands answer comes from; I believe that the initial equation should be placed by composition, wich generalizes matrix multiplication:
$$T(s \cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3))\circ T(t \cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3))=T((s+t) \cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3))$$

This time taking the derivative gives

\begin{align}
\theta_a \cdot A^a \circ  T[t \cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)] = \frac{d}{dt} T [t\cdot (\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)]
\end{align}

Where $A^a$ is given by the same equation. Does this sound right? If so, $A^a$ is a function and not an operator.

Comment: Note that T is now a function of six variables, three thetas and then three coordinatee for R^3.